# The footstone sank into the ground & is next to the coffin. Can I retrieve it?

Tags: halacha, kavod, cemetery-grave

One of my relatives foot stone (I think that's what they call the "plaque" that lies flat on the ground.) sank into the ground and is now next to the coffin. Is there any halachic problem if I climb into the pit to get it?

I may have to partially step on the coffin itself to gain leverage. I guess that's disrespectful to the dead, and maybe halachic problem, but, there's no other way. Is it any different, halachically, if a non-Jew does the job?

Comment: This is an interesting question, although you might want to see your rav, unless you're a kohen, in which case the answer is "no".

Comment: Also a very interesting question as I have been to Orthodox funerals where the person is being interred next to an existing grave and the tent and chairs are either over the existing grave or mourners have to walk on the existing grave to place soil on the new grave.  I do recognize this expands the intent of the question.

Comment: @Dennis - Yes, it does, in a sense. Where my relative is buried, there is a series of these footstones, and they are somewhat small, i.e., most likely smaller than the length of the pit / coffin. There is also very little space between the stones. So, ineveitably, when I visit, it is almost unavoidable to "step on someone else's toes".

Comment: Ask your orthodox Rabbi.,,,,,,,,,

Comment: You could reformulate it as, "What do people do when...?"